# Device compatibility problems in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play

I'm uploading an App to Google Play and there is about 2321 devices not compatibles with it. In order to test it I have setted all uses permissions to false (except openGl, for Maps V2). I'm using a lot of permissions but, for example, as far as I know Sony ST21 (http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_tipo-4718.php) has all my required features.

This are my required permissions (from Google Play):

```
android.hardware.CAMERA
android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS
android.hardware.LOCATION
android.hardware.location.GPS
android.hardware.location.NETWORK
android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN
```

And this are my permission inside Manifest:

```
<permission android:name="com.zonaapp.flamencomovil.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"  android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.zonaapp.flamencomovil.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Whats wrong with my Manifest Configuration?

Comment: Forgive a potentially stupid question but how do you know that permissions are your issue?

Comment: I'm not sure that permissions are my issue...

Comment: Well the way you phrased your question implies that the issues lies in your permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your min and max SDK version, those 2321 devices not compatibles with it may goes out of of your min & max sdk version.

So, provide min SDK version as below as and instead of max SDK or target SDK version provide latest android version.

Then it will cover lots of devices.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your permissions, you need to check the value of `minSdkVersion` in your manifest file. If it is very high, then many devices running older versions of Android won't support your app.

Comment: That's not a problem, I have API 7. Sony ST21 has ICS.